# Showing a sequence is in $\ell_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Suppose that $\varphi$ is an element of the dual of $\ell_2$. Then I need to show that the sequence $$(\varphi(e_1),\varphi(e_2), \varphi(e_3), \cdots)$$
is in $\ell_2$ (where $\{e_k\}$ is of course the standard basis for $\ell_2$).

So far, I've found that
$$ \begin{align*} 
\sum_{k = 1}^N |\varphi(e_k)|^2 &= \sum_{k = 1}^N \varphi(e_k) \varphi^*(e_k) \\
&= \varphi\left(\sum_{k = 1}^N e_k\varphi^*(e_k) \right)
\end{align*}
$$
This seems promising, but the best I can seem to do in order to bound the right-hand side is
$$
\begin{align*} 
\varphi\left(\sum_{k = 1}^N e_k\varphi^*(e_k) \right) &\leq \Vert \varphi \Vert \cdot \left\Vert \sum_{k = 1}^N e_k \varphi^*(e_k) \right\Vert \\
&\leq \Vert \varphi \Vert \cdot \left( \sum_{k = 1}^N \varphi^*(e_k) \right)^{1/2}
\end{align*} $$
which appears to go $\infty$ as $N \to \infty$. How can I find a better bound?

Comment: Hint: what does an element of the dual look like? Also, Parseval’s identity...

Comment: presumably it is $\phi^*(e_k)^2$ in your final expression as you are taking the L2 norm here on your L2 sequence.

Comment: And also yes follow the hint to under why this expression would converge to a finite number

Comment: Umm, the $\ell_2$-norm of $\sum_{k=1}^N e_k \overline{\phi(e_k)}$ is $\left[ \sum_{k=1}^N |\phi(e_k)|^2 \right]^{1/2}$.  So, with $\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^N |\phi(e_k)|^2$ you have $\lambda \le \lVert \phi \rVert \cdot \lambda^{1/2}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks, that should do it